# Is my uncertainty when fitting a curve to data from an oscilloscope too small?

Tags: capacitance, error-analysis, data-analysis

I was trying to measure the capacitance of a (large) capacitor using discharge decay. I saved the data from an oscilloscope while taking measurements, and it recorded about 250,000 points.

I noticed that, the more points I take, the smaller the covariance matrix values.
I noticed that my standard deviation was 0.1% of my actual value (if I take all the points). I'm not sure if it's a sensible value in uncertainty, because for this specific part of the experiment, we had to manually charge and discharge the capacitor using a 3-way switch.

The reason it doesn't make sense to me is because the curve fit doesn't look "perfect" and has quite a bit of wiggle room (which looks visually more than 0.1%).

Here's the equation I fit:

$$V = V_{0}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}},$$
where $V_0$ is my initial voltage at time t=0, R is the resistance (10k$\Omega$ roughly), and C is the capacitance.

[image: One of the measurements for discharge decay]

I set V_0 as an average of first 100 points initially.

Is it because I forced V_0 to be constant and would making it a variable in the fit give me a more reasonable estimate of the uncertainty?

Sorry here is the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bDj7L1d-u5fHJWpVV6mFYDjPUL3PuUP-?usp=sharing

Here's the function I defined:

```
def voltage(t, C, V_0):
    return V_0*np.exp(-t/(R*C))
```

Here is the value of capacitances from the 5 graphs and their std (keeping V_0 constant in this one) in mF.

[1.08394 1.10591 1.08278 1.06662 1.07464]

[1.1e-04 1.5e-04 1.1e-04 9.0e-05 8.0e-05]

And here we keep V_0 as a variable:

[1.07964 1.08435 1.08807 1.08135 1.07564]

[0.00016 0.00017 0.00016 0.00012 0.00011] in mF

In the 2nd one, we're getting a higher uncertainty in our fit of C, but when we notice that the values of C are more precise.
Hence in the first one,

$1.083 \pm 0.015$ mF is our value

and for the second one,

$1.082 \pm 0.005$ mF is what we get.

This is what I had done till now.

Comment: Have you plotted the curves after varying $C$ by $+/-1\sigma$ and comparing to the data and best fit? That should give you a visual sense of whether the error is reasonable or not.

Comment: @Andrew Okay so, I did that, which I was still not satisfied with. But here's what I did after. I set V_0 as a variable within the curve_fit I used. I got that the uncertainty in each of the capacitance value I got was similar (same order of magnitude - off by 30%) while taking V_0 as a variable (to when it was constant), and that V_0 had a really small uncertainty. So I think that's good? But when I took the average of all values from all 5 graphs keeping V_0 as a variable, my uncertainty was 1/3 than if I kept V_0 is a constant. I'm not sure as to which is more "accurate"?

Comment: So I think what is happening is, by allowing V_0 to vary, I am getting more "precise" values for my capacitance when I average C from different graphs/measurements (but less precise values for capacitance for each of the graphs individually). Whereas, if I force V_0 to be constant (and be the first value of my data), I'm getting less precise values (i.e higher uncertainty on capacitance - by a factor of 3) but more precise values (albeit by only 30%) for capacitance from each individual graphs. I think I should choose the graph where V_0 varies, as my main uncertainty, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Post your data somewhere and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: You report your results (v7) to a zillion significant figures.  Use the uncertainty as a guide for when to truncate. For example, $1.083\pm 0.015$ millifarad and $1.082\pm 0.005$ millifarad.

Comment: Apologies. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because I forced $V_0 $ to be constant and would making it a variable in the fit give me a more reasonable estimate of the uncertainty?

This type of assumption can totally screw up a single-parameter fit.  If you were to plot your residuals versus time (that is, data minus fit), you would have positive residuals at the start and end of the data and negative in the middle. This is a classic symptom of a bad model.

If you are going to go for a multi-parameter fit, I would suggest going whole hog: fit to

$$
V(t) = V_0 e^{-t/\tau} + V_\text{bias}
$$

where the “initial” voltage difference across the capacitor $V_0$, the time constant $\tau$ that you actually care about, and any nonzero bias $V_\text{bias}$ at the oscilloscope input are all free parameters.

You predict that $V_\text{bias}$ should be zero, but there are several ways that could be untrue. For example, your oscilloscope input could be miscalibrated or damaged. (One experiment I worked with was stuck with an oscilloscope with this problem for years, because it was easier to say “don’t believe that ground right there” than to spend \$10k on a replacement with the same features.) A more likely problem in your case is that the megaohm input to the scope is also forming an $RC$ filter with your circuit, so you have your ten-second time constant with your 10k resistor combined with a second exponential decay with a thousand-second time constant. Whether this is plausible depends on your circuit diagram in a way you may or may not care about, but if you got curious enough to test for it you might draw the same circuit if you used the ten megaohm probe that comes with your oscilloscope.

Another test you can make is to move your $V_0$ away from the tough-to analyze beginning of your dataset:

$$
V(t) = V_0 e^{-(t-t_0)/\tau} + V_\text{bias}
$$

where $t_0$ is not a free parameter but something you choose, like one second.  This choice lets you *test* whether your $V_0$ is good or not, by looking at a small region around $t_0$ and checking whether your data passes through the best-fit prediction for $V(t_0) = V_0 + V_\text{bias}$. This kind of offset also makes it easier to use the same fit if you decide there is some transient at the beginning and you try throwing away your first quarter-second of data.

If your fitting tool won’t do multiparameter fits, it might cost you less time to do it by hand than to switch tools.  Guess a $V_0$ like you already did, then plot chi-squared versus $V_\text{bias}$ for a few values, and pick a good minimum.  With your good $V_\text{bias}$, plot chi-squared versus $V_0$ for a few guesses, and pick a minimum for that parameter.  Repeat until you’re satisfied with the fit.

You are specifically asking about computing the *uncertainty* on the capacitance. In a multiparameter fit, uncertainties get complicated. If your data are well-behaved enough that a one-sigma error bound is “the same as” a 68% confidence interval, then a similar confidence interval will form a ellipsoid in your multiparameter space.  Your one-dimensional confidence intervals are like taking slices of this ellipsoid — which I think is what you describe in the comments where you can “trade uncertainty” between $V_0$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you. I added that variable and it seemed to have made the fit slightly better, and ~27% smaller uncertainty for the mean of my 5 values from each graph.
As for the oscilloscope acting as an RC filter, I was told that its resistance is 1 megaohm and a capacitance of 20pF in parallel to the capacitor I wanted to measure, so I thought it would be insignificant as it's ~8 orders of magnitude smaller.

Comment: Taking slices of the ellipsoid, or taking residuals? (or marginals, or whatever the formal name is, you know what I mean.) The former will always be smaller than the latter.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Honestly in this case, where there are actually multiple experiments in the dataset, I would report the uncertainty as the standard error of the mean of the best-fit values from the independent measurements. If I wanted to get into the weeds about the uncertainty of the fit results, the question would be whether the ensemble of fit results follows the distribution you would expect from their covariance matrices.

Answer (score 5):

I'd slightly change the approach. The expected analytical solution is $v(t) = v_0 e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$, and your measurements agree with the expected analytical solution.

Before performing a regression to fit the data, let's recast the solution as $\frac{v(t)}{v_0} = e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$ and

$RC = \dfrac{t}{\ln \left( \dfrac{v_0}{v(t)} \right)}$,

so that you can perform a **zero-th order** or **very low-order polynomial** regression, on a nearly constant function.
Here we are implicitly assuming that the random errors (because of noise or any other sources) on $\frac{v(t)}{v_0}$ and $t$ are not correlated from one time-step to the others. I can't justify rigorously this assumption right here and now, but it looks plausible to me.

Since the electrical noise seems to be larger than the absolute value of the measurement for large time, you can set a threshold on time (following a signal/noise ratio criterion, maybe) in order to avoid to use these noise-dominated measurements in the regression.

**Edit.** If you use the zero-th order recasting above, you'd probably end up with large uncertainties at the very beginning of the simulation, since the log at the denominator may be close to zero. Maybe it's better to look for a "first" order recasting,

$\ln \left( \dfrac{v_0}{v(t)} \right) = \dfrac{1}{RC} t$

Here you can see the results for a zero-th order and a first order recasting I've simulated on my laptop with ${RC^{exact}} = 1$,

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this approach because fitting a zero-order or first-order function better than fitting an exponential function? I suppose it has to do with how the algorithm minimises the error?

Comment: Because you can use linear regressions. Anyway, it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 2):

The key to your answer lies here:

> I noticed that, the more points I take, the smaller the covariance matrix values. I noticed that my standard deviation was 0.1% of my actual value (if I take all the points).

and in understanding what a fit actually does. Suppose our fit model reads $y_i = a x_i + b + \epsilon_i$, where $a$ and $b$ are our fit-parameters, $x$ is the predictor variable, $y$ is the response variable, and $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma)$ is a random error. Now, the standard deviation of the "best fit parameter" tells us something about the **average value** $E[y_i|x_i]$ and not about the spread $Sd[y_i|x_i]$ of the individual values $y_i$. Also, it does not tell us something about the quality/accuracy of the fit. Therefore, if we keep on adding more points $(x_i,y_i)$ to the dataset, we gain more and more confidence that the obtained fit values is best **assuming that the model is correct**.

This fact can be best shown by using simulations. The following plot shows two separates  fits to two datasets. However, the two datasets are constructed such that they have the same average value on every predictor variable $x_i$, but the red dataset has a five times larger standard deviation.
[image]

The resulting linear regression looks like this:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 17.1172590  0.2131045  80.323   <2e-16 ***
x            2.9917064  0.0749545  39.914   <2e-16 ***
grp5        -0.0007571  0.1435269  -0.005    0.996    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.209 on 1997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4437,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4432 
F-statistic: 796.5 on 2 and 1997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The "grp5" estimate tells us that there is no stat. significance difference **in the fit parameter** between the two datasets.

Therefore, to judge your fit you have to look either at *predictive intervals* (instead of confidence intervals), or you use such metrics a $R^2$.

So, what I recommend doing is to use a quadratic relationship and fitting a linear regression line, such like this:

[image]

Play with the number of datapoints and check the standard deviation of the fit-parameters ;)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem to have the statistical uncertainty ("Type A") covered. But the uncertainty in your extraction of $C$ will be larger than this due to systematic uncertainty ("Type B"). [NIST has a good reference on this](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Uncertainty/basic.html).

It's possible your Type B uncertainty will actually dominate your measurement because you can collect so much data that the Type A uncertainty is quite small (<0.1 %). For example, clearly your measurement of $C$ will only be as good as your knowledge of $R$. For the Type B uncertainty due to the value of $R$ to be insignificant, you'd probably need to know $R$ to at worst 100 parts per million (ppm, i.e. 1 part in $10^{-4}$). What is your uncertainty in $R$?

If you want an accurate overall estimate of uncertainty, you need to think about all the possible sources, including uncertainty in $R$, your oscilloscope's timebase accuracy, your oscilloscope's temperature stability, stray capacitance in your circuit, stray resistance in your capacitor, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this! The type B uncertainty is a little harder to quantify but is quite significant, especially the resistors and capacitors.

Comment: Yeah, when you dig into it, you realize that it can actually be a challenge to make absolute electrical measurements at the 0.1% uncertainty level and below. Read your oscilloscope and ohmmeter specs for absolute accuracy. And how long has it been since their last calibrations? It gets worse when you realize that you're technically not doing a DC measurement (although the frequencies in this case are probably low enough to call it one). For AC measurements, everything is more complicated.

Comment: I do not know when they were last calibrated as I was given the equipments without much information. We also used the function generator to produce a sine wave and use the phase difference between the two voltages to measure capacitance, but I have no idea how to deal with uncertainties in that.

Comment: @ManasvChhabra what did you use to measure the phase difference? A phasemeter? Or did you estimate the phases from oscilloscope traces somehow?

Comment: I used an oscilloscope. I propagated the errors (which is super annoying) and used a weighted mean and standard deviation to estimate the error on my capacitance. I think I got the hang of it. Still have to learn a lot more. The majority of error was due to the tolerance of the resistance.